# Authentication Problem on first Loging attempt 18.04

Tags: login, login-screen, 18.04

When I start my system and try logging in to my user in the first attempt event thought the password is correct the screen goes blank just showing the background and after a long while it shows `Authentication Error`.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Update 1:

This is all I could dig up from syslogs

```
Apr 28 15:05:35 akxer-Alienware-15-R3 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2155]: polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Apr 28 16:26:06 akxer-Alienware-15-R3 systemd[1]: Stopping Authorization Manager...
```

Comment: What is the exact error?  It's most likely caused by having run elevated commands that changed files in your personal space.  The exact error can make it more certain the culprit.

Comment: The only error I can see is Authentication Error and  nothing else, how do I find more information.

Comment: The last update of your question helped.  The first suspected culprit maybe unlikely.  This gives more to work with.

Comment: Try resetting your password from the console and see if that clears it up.  From the console run: `password`

Comment: I posted the below on May 27 in the answers section by mistake.  Didn't seem to have an option to move it, so recreated here today.
I am experiencing similar - the first login after a reboot works, then after that the above happens. I do notice that the second login screen looks a bit different so I think this is the right track. Uncommenting the WaylandEnable=False line has not worked though unfortunately.  As an update, with the latest iteration of Ubuntu, this does now seem to be solved for me.  Though I shifted from LTS to the bleeding edge version.

Comment: same problem. I cannot say that this problem is still there or not. I have 2 systems one with 18.04 and another with latest Ubuntu. Both of them are working fine without disabling wayland. So I have assumed that some update both in LTS as well as other versions has fixed this issue, so no need for the workaround given below.

Comment: Just in case if anyone still faces this issue and the answer below solves it please tell me and I will accept the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 too. I solved it by uncommenting `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` (forcing GDM to run under X11).